# ERROR "realloc(): invalid next size" when allocating memory to const char*** variable

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I have a function

`populateAvailableExtensions(const char** gAvailableExtensions[], int gCounter)`

which take a pointer to an array of strings and the number of elements in the array as parameters.

I allocate initial memory to that array using `malloc(0)`. Specs say that it will either return a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be passed to `free()`.

```
  int currentAvailableExtensionCount = gCounter;
```

This variable will store number of string in `gAvailableExtensions`.

Inside this `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < availableExtensionCount; ++i)
```

I have this piece of code

```
    size_t sizeOfAvailableExtensionName =
        sizeof(availableExtensionProperties[i].name);

    reallocStatus = realloc(*gAvailableExtensions, sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);

    memcpy(&(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount],
           &availableExtensionProperties[i].name,
           sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);

    ++currentAvailableExtensionCount;
```

where

```
availableExtensionProperties[i].name
```

returns a string.

This is how that `struct` is defined

```
typedef struct Stuff {
    char        name[MAX_POSSIBLE_NAME];
    ...
    ...
} Stuff;
```

---

```
realloc(*gAvailableExtensions, sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);
```

should add memory of size `sizeOfAvailableExtensionName` to `*gAvailableExtensions` de-referenced array.

```
memcpy(&(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount],
           &availableExtensionProperties[i].name,
           sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);
```

should copy the string (this `sizeOfAvailableExtensionName` much memory) from

```
&availableExtensionPropterties[i].name
```

address to

```
&(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount]
```

address.

---

But I don't think the code does what I think it should because I'm getting this error

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted
(core dumped) ./Executable
```

---

EDIT: Full code

```
uint32_t populateAvailableExtensions(const char** gAvailableExtensions[], int gCounter) {

  int currentAvailableExtensionCount = gCounter;

  void* reallocStatus;

  uint32_t availableExtensionCount = 0;

  vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
      VK_NULL_HANDLE, &availableExtensionCount, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

  VkExtensionProperties availableExtensionProperties[availableExtensionCount];

  vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(
      VK_NULL_HANDLE, &availableExtensionCount, availableExtensionProperties);

  for (int i = 0; i < availableExtensionCount; ++i) {

    size_t sizeOfAvailableExtensionName =
        sizeof(availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName);

    reallocStatus = realloc(*gAvailableExtensions, sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);

    memcpy(&(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount],
           availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName,
           sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);

    ++currentAvailableExtensionCount;
  }

  return currentAvailableExtensionCount;
}
```

This is how an external function calls on that one,

```
  uint32_t availableExtensionCount = 0;
  availableExtensions              = malloc(0);
  availableExtensionCount          = populateAvailableExtensions(&availableExtensions);
```

and

```
const char** availableExtensions;
```

is declared in header file.

EDIT 2: Updated the code, now `gCounter` holds the number of elements in `gAvailableExtensions`

Comment: Can you paste the whole code in one piece into your question?

Comment: That's not full code, what is `availableExtensionProperties`? What is `sizeof(availableExtensionProperties[i].name);`? `I allocate initial memory to that array using malloc(0)` don't do that, just assign `NULL`. `NULL` can be passed to `free` too. Your design would be easier if you would just use a struct instead of being a three star programmer. Can you post it all in a single compilable block of code so it's easy to read, copy, scan and search for errors?

Comment: @KamilCuk It's a struct, 6th code block in the question. Implementation similar to [`VkExtensionProperties`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkExtensionProperties.html). `sizeof(availableExtensionProperties[i].name)` should return size of the string and store it in `sizeOfAvailableExtensionName ` variable.

Comment: `&(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount]` I think you want `(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount]`. Also the `&availableExtensionProperties[i].name`, just `availableExtensionProperties[i].name` (in case you later change `name` to be a pointer). No worries - I understand what sizeof does. But the way your post is formatted into separated code snippets make it impossible for me to read. It's way better to post the code instead of describing what the code does. I know what "returns" or "does copy" or that code is inside a for, etc.

Comment: If the for executes, then your code leaks memory in `reallocStatus` and invalidates `*gAvailableExtensions` pointer (if realloc succeeds, most probably it does succeed). The pointer `*gAvailableExtensions` is invalid when you use it in `memcpy`. Also what is the point of `realloc` each time in a loop with the same size? `sizeof(availableExtensionProperties[i].name) should return size of the string` - `sizeof` returns the size of the variable, it returns `MAX_POSSIBLE_NAME` in this case. `strlen` would return the _length_ of the string without zero terminating character.

Comment: I wonder why you even come to `realloc()`:  With `uint32_t availableExtensionCount = 0;`you should not get into the for loop with `for (int i = 0; i < availableExtensionCount; ++i)`. Anyway, this condition does not make sense.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Sorry! I didn't to post full code and instead posted  stuff from my clipboard history. Fixed.

Comment: `sizeof()` in the first line of `populateAvailableExtensions()` doesn't do what you expect. Both will return pointer size. You can't use `sizeof()` to determine the size of an array passed as argument because that's decayed to a pointer

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ah makes sense. Will I have to keep a counter variable for the array then? Or is there a better way?

Comment: a counter passed as second arg is the appropriate way in most cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is totally messy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < availableExtensionCount; ++i) {

    size_t sizeOfAvailableExtensionName =
        sizeof(availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName);

    reallocStatus = realloc(*gAvailableExtensions, sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);

    memcpy(&(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount],
           availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName,
           sizeOfAvailableExtensionName);

    ++currentAvailableExtensionCount;
  }
```

I assume the only lines that does what you expect them to do, are the lines `for (int i = 0; i < availableExtensionCount; ++i)` and `++currentAvailableExtensionCount;`

First, the typical way to use `realloc` is like this:

```
foo *new_p = realloc(p, new_size);
if (!new_p)
   handle_error();
else
   p = new_p;
```

The point is that `realloc` will not update the value of `p` if a reallocation happens. It is your duty to update 'p'. In your case you never update `*gAvailableExtensions`. I also suspect that you don't calculate `sizeOfAvailableExtensionCount` correctly. The operator `sizeof` always return a compile time constant, so the `realloc` doesn't actuall make any sense.

The `memcpy` doesn't actally make any sense either, since you are copying the string into the memory of a pointer array (probably with an additional buffer overflow).

You said that `*gAvailableExtensions` is a pointer to an array of pointers to strings.
That means that you have to `realloc` the buffer to hold the correct number of pointers, and `malloc` memory for each string you want to store.

For this example, I assume that `.extensionName` is of type `char *` or `char[XXX]`:

```
// Calculate new size of pointer array
// TODO: Check for overflow
size_t new_array_size = 
  (currentAvailableExtensionCount + availableExtensionCount) * sizeof(*gAvailableExtensions);

char **tmp_ptr = realloc(*gAvailableExtensions, new_array_size);
if (!tmp_ptr)
    {
       //TODO: Handle error;
       return currentAvailableExtensionCount;
    } 
*gAvailableExtensions = tmp_ptr;

// Add strings to array
for (int i = 0; i < availableExtensionCount; ++i) 
  {
    size_t length = strlen(availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName);

    // Allocate space for new string
    char *new_s = malloc(length + 1); 
    if (!new_s)
       { 
         //TODO: Handle error;
         return currentAvailableExtensionCount;
       }

    // Copy string
    memcpy (new_s, availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName, length + 1);

    // Insert string in array
    (*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount] = new_s;

    ++currentAvailableExtensionCount;
  }
```

If you can guarantee that the lifetime of `availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName` is longer than `*gAvailableExtensions`, you can simplify this a little bit by dropping `malloc` and `memcpy` in the loop, and do:

```
char *new_s  = availableExtensionProperties[i].extensionName;
(*gAvailableExtensions)[currentAvailableExtensionCount] = new_s;
```

Some harsh words at the end: It seems like you have the "Infinite number of Monkeys" approach to programming, just hitting the keyboard until it works.

Such programs will just only give the illusion of working. They *will* break in spectacular ways sooner or later.

Programming is not a guessing game. You *have* to understand every piece of code you write before you move to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentAvailableExtensionCount =
     sizeof(*gAvailableExtensions) / sizeof(**gAvailableExtensions) - 1;
```

is just a obfuscated way of saying

```
int currentAvailableExtensionCount = 0;
```

I stopped reading after that, because i assume that is not what you intend to write.

Pointers in `c` doesn't know how many elements there are in the sequence they are pointing at. They only know the size of a single element.

In your case `*gAvailableExtensions` is of type of `char **` and `**gAvailableExtensions` is of type `char *`. Both are pointers and have the same size on a typical desktop system. So on a 64 bit desktop system the expression turns into 
`8/8 - 1`, which equals zero.

Unless you fix this bug, or clarify that you actually want the value to always be zero, the rest of the code does not make any sense.

Comment: Fixed it. Now the functions takes in a counter variable that holds number of elements already in the array. Because the function is the first one in the routine, that variable should always be 0. So `int currentAvailableExtensionCount = 0;` is also correct.